# A box keeps appearing under the cursor

Tags: c++, qt, cursor

I've almost finished my first (and big...) Qt app, and first time using Qt Creator (Qt 5.4.0)  But one problem remains.

When I stop moving my cursor, this thing appears below, within app window

[image: http://i.imgur.com/zbtij4u.png]

Once it appears, it disappears only when I start moving it again, just to pop-up immediately when I stop.

I have 2k lines of code and none of it is in any way connected to mousepads. What's that?

Comment: Nice... a 3d cursor with shadow :-)

Comment: Looks like an empty 3d tooltip

Comment: how do I turn that off? It's not in-code, and this is the first time I'm using Qt creator.

Comment: Check in your *.ui files whether any widget has empty spaces set for tooltip

Comment: The only thing I found about that is http://www.qtforum.org/article/13609/qt4-removing-a-tool-tip.html

Comment: There shouldn't be tooltips if you don't set them. Maybe you're setting strings with only spaces or something (like Lahiru Chandima suggests). grep UI files and code for "toolTip/ToolTip".

Comment: there is not a single mention of "tip" nor "tool" (other than toolBar) in the *.ui file

Comment: whatd'ya know. Appereantly CTRL+F "Tip" is not reliable anymore. There was a blank ToolTip in the ui file. Deleted it, and now everythings the way it should be. Thanks