# Tooltip-like squares on a QCustomPlot widget

Tags: c++, qt, plot, tooltip, qcustomplot

I am using QCustomPlot in Qt Creator. I haven't specified any tooltips for my widget or anything. When I hold down my cursor on the plot without moving, an empty tooltip-like thing appears. I am wondering how to turn this off. I appreciate any hint in this matter.

[image]

Comment: Please check it carefully, it could be an empty space character. You my call `toolTip()` at runtime to see if any tool tip string has been set.

Comment: check in the ui file whether an empty tooltip is set to the widget

Comment: See the related question: [*A box keeps appearing under the cursor*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29938796/a-box-keeps-appearing-under-the-cursor), asked just few days ago.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for help guys, in the MainWindow.ui file I had to remove this part of code (it was auto generated):

```
<property name="toolTip">
   <string>&lt;html&gt;&lt;head/&gt;&lt;body&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;br/&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/body&gt;&lt;/html&gt;</string>
</property>
```

Comment: Strange...I never had this problem before when using auto-generated `QMainWindow` template. I use Qt 4.8.6 by the way. Mind share yours?

Comment: QMake version 3.0
Using Qt version 5.3.2 in B:/Qt/5.3/mingw482_32/lib